# Replacing quotes but keeping UTF-8 characters unaltered

Tags: php, utf-8

Short question you guys: I have a PHP string which may or maybe not contain quotes, but it surely contains UTF-8 characters like ă, î, ş, ţ or â. What I would like to do is escape those quotes (so I can display the string in a text input) but keep the characters unaltered (for example don't transform î in "& amp;amp;icirc;").

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), which targets *only* `<`, `>`, ampersands and single and/or double quotes, depending on both the provided character set and quote-escaping commands.

This is as opposed to [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities), which encodes *everything*.  If your input is in UTF-8, and your output is also in UTF-8, you shouldn't need to encode any entities in your string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Charles. I tried that but I get something like this: &amp;quot; wheen I display the string in a html text box.

Comment: Set the 4th parameter to `false`, which will prevent the double-encode that you're seeing.

Comment: Weird... Fourth parameter should not be necessary if the source string is plain text.